# FTP server timeouts on passive, I can only use active

Tags: linux, ftp

I am running Proftpd on Ubuntu Server 10.04. Filezilla was configured to switch to active mode on failure but connection fails at MLSD time out; Filezilla needs to prefer active mode to connect. Coreftp switched to active from passive and used LIST instead. I don't think I specifically need passive mode but I have a shallow understanding from Google results that passive is encouraged. Although I am behind a NAT for troubleshooting I am using my own network's allocated IPs. Otherwise I have a business line so external IP is static and the cable company's router forwards ports to the server. Is my server misconfigured for passive mode and if so: Is it important to get passive mode working? and how it could be done.

[Client logs & proftpd.conf](https://gist.github.com/9e17dc5438942c2230bd)

Comment: Why are you using FTP? SCP or SFTP are far better protocols. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/FtpMustDie

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see, you are connecting to your *internal* ip (192.168.1.53) but the server gives its *external* IP (71.127.90.47) according to *MasqueradeAddress* directive.
You are also using TLS, that's why the router may not be able to track the FTP connection.

I had the same problem with my pureftpd server and worked it around with launching two different addresses to announce (like MasqueradeAddress in your case) one for internal zone and one for external (external address is being staticaly NATed be ciso router). These server processes listen to different ports (10021 and 20021). I also added these strings to my iptables config:

```
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 10021
-A PREROUTING -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 20021
```

As you see, all requests from internal networ are redirected to "local" server and all others are redirected to "internet" server.

I hope, I understood the problem right and my explanation is clear enough.

P.S. About FTPtest.net. I also tested my server with this tester, but it hav very strict rules. My tests passed with http://www.net2ftp.com/

Comment: I ran into troubles executing your suggestions and I have a feeling I did it wrong. [github](https://gist.github.com/ac204863852442131aca)

Comment: What kind of trouble? Have a look at tcpdump.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler answer is to set your ftp client to active mode. Filezilla has it under the 'transfer settings' listed.

May be not very neat, but it worked for me ;)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question that was posed.  Yes it may allow the asker to accomplish the task, but not how to solve the problem so they can use passive.